# Can form flow fields in bot framework be pre-populated?

Tags: c#, botframework

I have used formflow to ask several questions and to finally fill up a form. A unique id is generated and given to user at the end. Now using that unique id I want to edit the form. Is it possible to pre-populate the fields? Or is there any other way to do so?

This is the code that I am using to create a form for first time:

```
public static IForm<AssesmentHelper> BuildForm()
{
    OnCompletionAsyncDelegate<AssesmentHelper> wrapUpRequest = async (context, state) =>
    {
       //Do something....
    };

    return new FormBuilder<AssesmentHelper>()
            .Message(Responses.NumberSelection)
            .Field(nameof(Name))
            .Field(nameof(Age))
            .Field(nameof(Address))
            .Field(nameof(Information))
            .Field(nameof(Email), validate: ValidateMailId)
            .AddRemainingFields()
            .OnCompletion(wrapUpRequest)
            .Build();
}
```

Now, I want to pre-populate fields (Name, Age, Address) so that I can use it for editing as well.

Comment: Please share the code you have tried

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can pass an instance of your Form state/model to the FormDialog with the Form parameters pre-filled (as you can see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureBot/blob/b2bb8c4457b6cafca1bafb275a285e1ba0c997f8/AzureBot/Dialogs/ActionDialog.cs#L217)). Have in mind that . if you do that, any step for filling a field is skipped if that field has a value.

If you still want to ask for those parameters even if they have a value; you must change the FormOptions and use [FormOptions.PromptFieldsWithValues](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/dd/df7/namespace_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_form_flow.html#a27be39918296ad3536d6a5c8d6ed5394aa796e574d8cf50f288b2e44ecd64764a), which will prompt for fields, but use the passed in state for defaults.

The relevant docs for this are [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/forms.html#initialState).

Comment: Thanks Jadib. If possible can you help me with code, how to use  FormOptions.PromptFieldsWithValues in form flow? I tried like:   FormBuilder<AssesmentHelper>(FormOptions.PromptFieldsWithValues)
                    .Message(Responses.NumberSelection)
                    .Field(nameof(Program)).. But it gives an error. @sangam , I have used this code

Comment: The FormOptions needs to be specified on the FormsDialog not on the builder. You can create the form dialog in the following way: var form = new FormDialog<FormState>(formState,
                BuildForm,
                FormOptions.PromptFieldsWithVal‌ues). Please vote it/mark it as answered if this helped you

Comment: Thanks Jadib. I will implement it using Forms Dialog

Comment: An example link from @ezequiel-jadib to ActionDialog.cs is broken and can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureBot/blob/b2bb8c4457b6cafca1bafb275a285e1ba0c997f8/AzureBot/Dialogs/ActionDialog.cs).

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can pre-populate the formflow fields
Firstly you will look for the fields that you want to populate and then add them to the entity list

I am using LUIS and if i find a suitable entity from my LUIS result i will add it to the form to be pre-populated.

```
 var entities = new List<EntityRecommendation>(result.Entities);
  if (entities.Any(e => e.Type == "IdNumber"))
        {
            entities.Add(new EntityRecommendation(type: "IdNumber") { Entity = entities.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Type == "IdNumber").Entity});
        }
```

This will be done before you call your form to be built.
Just make sure your "type" is the property name of your class.
"Entity" will be the value