# Start FormFlow from where it was stopped

Tags: c#, botframework

Following the AnnotatedSandwichBot example, one can handle form filling cancelation with this:

```
    private static IDialog<object> MakeRootDialog()
    {
        return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(Form.BuilLocalizedForm))
            .Do(async (context, state) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var completed = await state;
                }
                catch (FormCanceledException canceled)
                {
                    if (canceled.InnerException == null)
                        await context.PostAsync($"You quit on {canceled.Last}");
                    else
                        await context.PostAsync($"Sorry, I have a problem here");
                }
            });
```

When the user suddenly types "bye", the bot successfully says `You quit on FieldName` (and a huge stack trace afterwards with a FormCanceledException on Bot Emulator).

But if I just say something again, it will start the form from the beggining instead of starting from the last completed step. How could I make it so the form starts from there - and ideally printing something like "Welcome back!"?

Comment: The docs on the Bot State Service says it's purpose is to solve questions like *what was the last question I asked them?*, but I'm not sure how/where to integrate that with FormFlow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should catch a `FormCanceledException<T>` where T is your form model. Once you do that, you should be able to access to the [LastForm](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/5cf71c742f27d89e9dbc4076f850122bd6edac11/CSharp/Library/FormFlow/IFormDialog.cs#L252) property of the exception, where you will find the partial form when the user quits.

Then you can use that partial form as the initial state of your form (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40507449/can-form-flow-fields-in-bot-framework-be-pre-populated) related question).