# Bot for multi-purpose auto reply (Microsoft Bot Framework)

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm making a Bot that can reply e-comerce websites (such as book shop, flower shop, motorbike shop,etc..) using **FormFlow** to create the selection that I've stored in my database. The problem here is that how can the bot provides to my customers the correct selections according to the purpose of the Website (For instance: customers chat with the bot via Flower Shop website so the bot must give the selections that relate to "Flower" to customers and customers chat from others websites must receive the correctspoding selections). I really don't know how to pass the ServiceUrl to FormFlow class to identify the selections should the Bot reply?

Comment: And how the service url will help you to identify that? Are you using a custom client? Because if you are using the webchat, the service url will be always the same

Comment: I'm using DirectLine, so the ServiceUrl will help me to identify where the message come from

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can form flow fields in bot framework be pre-populated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40507449/can-form-flow-fields-in-bot-framework-be-pre-populated)

Comment: @EzequielJadib my situation here is I want to get the ServiceUrl

Comment: You want to get the ServiceUrl or you want to pass the ServiceUrl to the FormFlow? Your question was around how to pass the ServiceUrl to FormFow.

Comment: @EzequielJadib I want to pass the ServiceUrl to the FormFlow/ or is there anyway to get it in the FormFlow class ?

Comment: I you want to pass it, then it's a duplicate of the other question. You instantiate your form model, and pass the serviceUrl to the model. Then in the formflow the serviceUrl will be accessible because formflow has access to the model, like this https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureBot/blob/master/AzureBot.Services.VMs/Forms/VirtualMachineFormState.cs#L10 and this https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureBot/blob/master/AzureBot.Services.VMs/Dialogs/VMDialog.cs#L152

Comment: @EzequielJadib did you mean I have to create a class such as ProductOrder class and build a FormFlow base-on it? However, I still didn't know how can we assign it to the Object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137571/discussion-between-ezequiel-jadib-and-justin-van).

Comment: Hello, @EzequielJadib as my question i've asked above, if I embed a chat control which connect to DirectLine, will my bot can recognize exactly ServiceUrl of the Client(For instance: embed in abc.com so the ServiceUrl that the bot receive will abc.com)

Comment: you can catch the phrase and parse it using regex, then match it against your "key phrases", I'm guessing you have one, if not you can create one on your database